# Android.mk: Unsupported source file extensions for C files

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

In my Android.mk file i have something like this

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)    
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := testmodule
FILE_LIST := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/md5/md5.с
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/md5/md5main.с

FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

but when i run `ndk-build` - i get the following error

```
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in /Users/some/path/jni/Android.mk for module testmodule    
Android NDK:   include/md5/md5.с include/md5/md5main.с
```

(I use android-ndk-r8c on OSX 10.9.2)

How can i add *.c file the Android.mk? What could i be doing wrong?

(I can post more of the Android.mk and Application.mk if needed)

Comment: You could rename them to .cpp and if that is not possible create a .cpp file in which you include both .c files.

Comment: What is `LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to move the answer from the comments, like @greenapps said this works:

```
You could rename them to .cpp and if that is not possible
create a .cpp file in which you include both .c files.
```